# HTML access resource before resource is loaded

Tags: angular

I new to angular I use angular 8 in my project.

My html element try to display data that still not loaded.
Here is the HTML :

```
   <tr *ngFor="let p of products; let i = index;">
        <td width="">{{productType(p.productTypeId)}}</td>
   </tr>
```

productType is function that returns value to display from component.

Here is defenition of productType function:

```
productType(id){
    return this.productTypes.find(x => x.id === id).text;
}
```

Here is how I load resources:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.productTypeService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
        this.productTypes = data;
    });

    this.productService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
        this.products = data;
    });
}
```

But it seems that when  productType is triggered productTypes resources still not loaded.

So my question is there any way to fix the bug?

Comment: if you could add in the question an example payload of both requests, i'll create a stackblitz of a reactive way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's just a matter of dealing with asynchronous data. What you could do, is only render the data once the `this.productTypes` has the data using the `ngIf` directive.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="this.productTypes">
  <tr *ngFor="let p of products; let i = index;">
    <td width="">{{productType(p.productTypeId)}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

More on [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

**Alternative**

Combine both streams of data into one observable

```js
ngOnInit(){
  combineLatest([
    this.productService.getAll(), 
    this.productTypeService.getAll()]
  )
  .pipe(
    map(([products, productTypes]) = > {
      return products.map((product) => 
        ({
          ...product,
          productType: productTypes.find(product => product.id === id).text
        })
      )
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.products = data;
  });
}
```

Then your html will look like:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let p of products; let i = index;">
  <td width="">{{p.productType}}</td>
</tr>
```

Read on [combineLatest](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest)

You could go all out and not subscribe but use the `async` pipe in the template. [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: what is combineLatest?is it some kind function?

Comment: updated answer with link to docs. Yes its a function from RxJS thats similar to `Promise.all()` if you're familiar with that

Answer (score 0):

I thin you need to try requests with `forkJoin` for get the datas at time

You need import it from rxjs like this
`import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/forkJoin';`

```
ngOnInit() {
forkJoin([
this.productTypeService.getAll(), 
 this.productService.getAll()
]).subscribe(response => {
// where response[0] is the response of this.productTypeService.getAll()
 this.productTypes = response[0];
// and response[1] is the response of this.productService.getAll()
    this.products = response[1]
})

}
```

is This what you want ?